# How do i setup munin plugin multiping

Tags: munin

According to the plugin:

```
The following environment variables are used

 ping_args  - Arguments to ping (default "-c 2")
 ping_args2 - Arguments after the host name (required for Solaris)
 ping       - Ping program to use
 host       - Host to ping

Configuration example

 [multiping]
  env.host www.example.org mail.example.org
```

where do i specify the [multiping]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should write this configuration into a new file located in

`/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d`

or add these two lines at the end of file

`/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node`